# Nginx redirect not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect `localhost/api` to another location(127.0.0.1:3000)

here is the config file

```
server{

listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

   server_name _;

        location /api{
           root 127.0.0.1:3000;
         }

}
```

But i got `404` error

Comment: I take it you have something running on port `3000` you need to look at `proxy_pass` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: i got the following error invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:44 when i add this ` proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Update the question with the changes you made and the output of `nginx -t`

Comment: proxy_pass parameter needs to be URL, not just hostname:port. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue with `proxy_pass`

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/;
```